# How to get element value in jquery list with unknown type

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am having the below list in HTML

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="li1" class="ui-state-default"><asp:Button Text='Test1' runat='server'/></li>
    <li id="li2" class="ui-state-default"><asp:Button Text='Test2'  runat='server'/></li>
    <li id="li3" class="ui-state-default"><asp:Button Text='Test3'  runat='server'/></li>
    <li id="li4" class="ui-state-default"><asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='testing'></asp:TextBox></li>
    <li id="li5" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li id="li6" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li id="li7" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

now i want to alert the values when dragging the list items. 
For e.g if i drag the textbox then it should display the textbox value .

EDIT:
I am new to Jquery I have tried as shown below to get the ordered element now i want to know the value of the each list item ?? how to do this ??

```
 $(function() {
            $("#sortable").sortable({
                update: function() {
                    var ElementsOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray'); //.toString();                        
                    alert(JSON.stringify(ElementsOrder));
                    var xxx = { pages: $(this).sortable('toArray') };
                    alert(JSON.stringify(xxx));
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Note: if you alert anything while dragging, the drag will stop.

Comment: i am just trying to see the value of the element. so i can remove the alert and store it in the variable.